# How to typeset creative commons analogous character of ©?

Tags: symbols, characters

I'm aware how to use creative commons logo. But I'm searching for a character that I can insert in a caption to notice that the image (in my case) is under creative commons and not under ©, so it should be like a double "c" or something like that. So is there a creative commons analogous symbol of "©" that I can insert like a character?

Comment: You are probably searching for `\copyright`.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I'm trying to do something like a "CC" symbol analogous to © but C is for copyright I want a symbol for a creative commons image in my case...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The  [ccicons](http://ctan.org/pkg/ccicons)  package seems to be what you are looking for. (I've never used it myself though.) With the command `ccLogo` you will get one of these:

[image: ccicons icon]

There is also a [cclicenses](http://ctan.org/pkg/cclicenses) package, but the icons are not as clear nor as up-to-date.

[image: cclicenses]

Comment: Welcome! Can you expand your answer a little bit more? Maybe a small example with an image is useful.

Comment: Sure thing, just added images in now.

Comment: Tested works!Thanks, congratulations great start!

Comment: another possibility is to google for "creative commons icons", which will also show some other images, including one that looks like a "c" rotated 180 degrees with an arrowhead pointing downward on the appropriate terminal of the "c".  (but the ready-made font with "cc" is likely to be easier to use.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't find it...Can you post a link? Thanks!

Comment: @GM -- not a direct link (i'm on the road and the browser I have access to doesn't report accurate urls), but try this: go to google.co.jp, search for "creative commons icons", go down the page to images, then choose "more images".  there are many shown, including the one I described.

Comment: This one, right?: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Cc-sa.svg/220px-Cc-sa.svg.png since its available as SVG one can easily define a macro including the image as symbol …